# Add Google as Default Search Provider for Windows 8.1 IE 11

Tags: windows-8.1, default-settings, internet-explorer-11

I have been trying with no luck to use Google as the default search provider for IE11 on Windows 8.1

Currently I can only add Google Australia as an "Accelerator" however this does not provide the capability to search Google from the IE11 address bar.

It currently seems that unless your IE11 came with multiple built in search providers, you are pretty much stuck with Bing for now.

Has anyone figured out how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Click on the gear in the top right corner of IE.
2. Click on ***Manage add-ons***
3. In ***Add-on Type*** select ***Search Providers***
4. In the bottom of the window, click on ***Find more search providers ...***
5. A new window will open, click on ***Google Search***

   1. ***NOTE:*** If nothing happens after clicking ***Google Search*** press ***F12*** and the ***Developer Tools*** will appear in the bottom of the window.
   2. Scroll to the bottom of the ***Developer Tools*** window and click on the monitor and smartphone icon, (the Emulation icon, you can also press ***Ctrl + 8***).
   3. In the ***Mode*** section, change ***Document mode*** to ***10***.
   4. After the page reloads, click on ***Google Search***
6. Click on ***Add to Internet Explorer***
7. A pop up appears. Check ***Make this my default search provider***.
8. Click on ***Add***

And that's all, you are all set!!!

NOTE: Check comments for extra info

Comment: The new window from step 5 did not have Google Search in the list. I realised that I am being sent to a en-au specific page  http://www.iegallery.com/en-au/addons?callback=true&featuretype=2 and when I manually edited en-au to be en-us the Google Search result was present. I did not require the sub steps for step 5. On that basis, this answer is correct. I also tested whether my searched from the IE11 address bar were then directed to the Google Australia site an they were.

Comment: For step 5, if you do not see Google on the list, go to the following page to add the Google search provider: http://www.iegallery.com/en-us/Addons/Details/813. **NOTE:** If you have the IE update [KB3038314](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3038314), then this needs to be uninstalled first.