# Add Google as Default Search Provider in IE 11

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, search

Google Chrome becomes more and more unusable: crashing, eating memory, etc.
So I decided to come back to IE and use it as my default browser. Chrome used to be much faster. But not recently. It slows down all my laptops now. 
The first thing I wanted to do after starting using IE is to change Bing to Google Search as the search engine for toolbar searches. 
I go to that page to add Google Search Add-on:

http://www.iegallery.com/en-us/addons?callback=true&featuretype=2

And it is not there.
I tried on both Win8 and Win7. Am I missing something? Can anybody else install Google Search Add-on for IE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 11

- Open Internet Explorer.
- In the top right corner of the search box, click the down arrow.
- Click Add.
- Select Google.
- Click Add to Internet Explorer.
- Check the box next to"Make this my default search provider."
- Click Add.

More Details: [Add Google as Default Search Provider for Windows 8.1 IE 11](https://superuser.com/questions/696952/add-google-as-default-search-provider-for-windows-8-1-ie-11)

Comment: Flag the question as a duplicate if you're simply going to link to a previous answer.

Comment: @Karan: Steps listed are different and the link provides more option apart from those steps :)

Comment: If yours is truly an independent answer that is confirmed to work then you can add it to that question, which this one is a duplicate of.

Comment: Thanks karan, Will make sure to flag it as duplicate from now. :)

Comment: I know it is duplicate guys. The problem is that when I follow the steps listed above and go to the link provided - I don't see Google Search as an option. Question to you: DO YOU SEE GOOGLE SEARCH there as an option?

Comment: Yes, it does show google & bing symbol - Just select google symbol and good to go :)